# Is it possible to update the 'QT GUI Label' when flowgraph is running?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using an 'Import' block to import a Python function, then I am using this function to calculate a value for a variable in the 'Variable' block, and finally I am using 'QT GUI Label' block to show the value of this variable. This works fine, and it shows the value as it was at the start of the flowgraph.

Is it possible to make the 'QT GUI Label' to periodically update the value of the variable when flowgraph is running ?

I have tried to use the 'Function probe' block for this purpose, in such a way that it probes the value of the variable in the 'Variable' block. However, it does not work.

What is the correct way to use 'Function probe' block in this case, or is it even possible ?

I am using  GRC 3.9.5.0 (Python 3.8.10)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the 'QT GUI Label'

Yes.

> to periodically update the value of the variable when flowgraph is running ?

This sounds like you should not be using QT GUI Label, but the QT Number Sink instead. Since that number seems to change over the runtime of the flow graph, I interpret that this is actually part of the signal processing you do.

Instead of writing a python function that, separate to all the number processing in the GNU Radio flow graph, calculates a number, write a python GNU Radio block!

The idea is that you work *within* GNU Radio, not *against* it. Write your block, integrate its input into your flowgraph, and connect its output to the appropriate Instrumentation sink: that's the GNU Radio way.

Comment: I should have said that the value of the variable is not used in signal processing. I want to show the value of the variable so that the user of GRC gets an idea of how the variable is changing. It is slowly varying, so it is enough to update it once a second or so. I thought that 'Function probe' is a good solution because with it one can easily set the poll rate.

Comment: But you say you want to *display* the value, so it *is* used; and it *seems to be part of the signal processing*, even if just for display :) Where exactly does the value come from? What does it signify? again, unlikely that you want anything but a simple python GNU Radio block :) But I'm happy if you can convince me otherwise!

Comment: I am using GRC for radio-astronomy, and I want to display the coordinates (azimuth and elevation) of a source on the sky. They are not used in signal processing. I have put the calculation of these parameters within the Python block which is used for signal processing, but then they are calculated within each run of the work-function, which is much more frequent than needed. Furthermore, I start to get the 'OOO' signs (=overflow), which means that after the calculation of the parameters there is not enough time for actual signal processing.

Comment: well the thing is you have, through decimation, arbitrary control about how often a work function is called, if you put that functionality into its own block. They really *are signal processing steps that you, as a human, are using* :) But no matter how we help you implement that, you'll need to tell us from what the polar coordinates are calculated :) Is it from samples flowing through the flow graph, or is it something completely external, e.g. a motor control unit being queried?

Comment: The current location of the source on the sky can be calculated if we know 1) ecliptic or galactic coordinates of the source, 2) location of the observer on Earth, and 3) current time. The items 1) and 2) are given by the user via the 'QT GUI Entry' blocks. So all the information needed, except current time, are given manually. I am using Python's Astropy package for the coordinate calculation.

Comment: @Kimmo ah! But then the GNU Radio function probe gives you absolutely nothing. Just, when you're done with the calculation, set the text on the label.

Comment: I have the following solution: I make an embedded Python block, which has been configured as a signal source. In the work function I am just calculating whatever parameters I need, for example the coordinates of a source on the sky. The work function includes the command `time.sleep(1.0)`, so the effect on the CPU load is minimal.  The Python block has an output for each parameter, and the outputs are connected to  'QT GUI Number Sinks'. This works nicely. Can this be considered as an acceptable solution ?

Comment: sounds fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a variable, which is not part of the signal processing itself, but you want to display the value of the parameter when flowgraph is running, you can do the following.

- Make a Python (or C++) block which is configured as a signal source, that is, set `in_sig=None`.
- Use the work-function of the block to calculate the value(s) for the variable(s). In the work-function, insert a command like `time.sleep(1.0)`, so that the block does not use too much CPU time. In the block, make an output for each variable, and fill the `output_items` with the variable(s).
- Connect the outputs to 'QT GUI Number Sinks'. There, you can also set the value of 'Update Period' to a value similar to the `time.sleep` command above.